# Find string at end of variable - Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, variables, input, echo

I am writing a batch script that receives commands and runs them. I need to examine the user's input for a string at the end of the input. For example, say a user types in `ECHO Hello World & ECHO ON`, and the variable this command is stored in is `%CHO%`, how can I find the `& ECHO ON` at the end of the variable?

I already have a way to find `ECHO ON &` in the input, but I need a way to check if `& ECHO ON` is at the end of the variable. If I were to just check for `& ECHO ON`, the script can easily mistaken `& ECHO ONWARDS` or something like that and think it is actually `& ECHO ON`.

Any ideas as of how this can be done?

Comment: You can use a substring as outlined in the help file for the `SET` command. `IF /I "echo on"=="%cho:~-7%" echo match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - it should be able to handle special symbols too (it uses [endsWith](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/stringutils/endsWith.bat) subroutine):

```
@echo off

:::example calls of :endsWith subroutine

call :endsWith abcdefgh fgh
echo %errorlevel%
call :endsWith abcdefgh abc
echo %errorlevel%

exit /b 0

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::    
:endsWith [%1 - string to be checked;%2 - string for checking ]
@echo off
rem :: sets errorlevel to 1 if %1 ends with %2 else sets errorlevel to 0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "string=%~1"
set "checker=%~2"

set LF=^


rem ** Two empty lines are required
rem echo off
for %%L in ("!LF!") DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%R in ("!checker!") do ( 
        set "var=!string:%%~R=%%L#!"
    )
)

for /f "delims=" %%P in (""!var!"") DO (
    set "temp=%%~P"
)

if "%temp%" EQU "#" (
    endlocal & exit /b 1
) else (
    endlocal & exit /b 0
)
goto :eof
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

You can also use `FINDSTR` (probably will be slower as it relies on external commands):

```
echo abcdefgh| findstr /e "fgh" >nul 2>nul && (
   echo ends with 
)||(
  echo  does not ends with
)
```

Comment: Interesting, seems a bit much. Is there any simpler way?

Comment: @ChristianSirolli - check my update (you might still need to add some tricks for the special symbols).Though you can use the code as a standalone function without worrying about the complexity in there

Comment: How do I use it as a standalone function?

Comment: @ChristianSirolli  - I've added examples calls in the first code snippet

Comment: Could you explain what it does?

Comment: @ChristianSirolli - it replaces all occurrences in the  original string of the string you want to check with `{new.line}#` and then checks if the last string is equal to `#`  , it is a little bit more complex in order to process the special characters.